# Apex Continuation method that call service method

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, continuation

We have a a service class where we use as repository/factory for specific external endpoint. One of those endpoint has a method which takes sometime and for that reason we get a timeout exception since we are making a sync call.

We started to use Apex Continuation but we get the following error:

> Apex methods for continuation can not be invoked from a non-continuation action.

There is not so much documentation, we think the cause of the error it's because the invocation of the service we have implemented.

```
@AuraEnabled(continuation=true cacheable=true)
public static Object updateListSubscription(String subscriptionList, String conctactId){

    HttpRequest request = HTTP_InformaticaInterface.UpdateListSubscription(conctactId, subscriptionList);
    Continuation cont = new Continuation(60);
    cont.state = cont.addHttpRequest(request);
    cont.ContinuationMethod = 'updateListSubscriptionCallback';
    return cont;
}

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Boolean updateListSubscriptionCallback(List<String> labels, Object state){
    HttpResponse response = Continuation.getResponse(labels[0]);
    return response.getStatusCode() == 200;
}
```

how can we use the "UpdateListSubscription" method in the context of a continuation method?

Comment: So `UpdateListSubscription` method is called from AUra component's jS right?

Comment: Yes It's called from the JS

Comment: I tried your code and was able to do all, witthout any issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LWC import must get Apex method from **apexCountinuation** but not **apex** resource.

```
'@salesforce/apexContinuation/ApexClass.ClassMethod';
```

not

```
'@salesforce/apex/ApexClass.ClassMethod';
```